# Android studio error - missing class file

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

I'm working on an app and a while ago it was still working and it was building just fine, but after a few minutes of coding, I tried to build again then an error showed up:

> "error: cannot access zzbck class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found"

**Code:**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //widgets
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;

    //vars

    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mSearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);

        getLocationPermission();

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: Initializing");

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        ||  keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //execute method for searching
                    geoLocate();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");

        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "GeoLocate: found a Location: " +address.toString());

           // Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT()).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the device's current location.");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted){

                final com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Found Location");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                                moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                        DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                        "My Location");

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current Location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " +latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));

        if(!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);

            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();

    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            initMap();

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted.");
                    //initializing map
                    initMap();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

}
```

**build.gradle:**

Module level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lrtapp.ardentmap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'

    //Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try using latest version of **Firebase-Messaging** to this `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.3'`

Comment: so, i should delete and replace the one on my code? which is the 11.4.0?

Comment: Go to module level gradle, find `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'` & replace to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.3'`.

Comment: thank you! will try that as soon as i got home.

Comment: i tried it bro, then this showed up.

Comment: Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/zekee/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.pom
    file:/C:/Users/zekee/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.jar
    file:/C:/Users/zekee/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.pom

Comment: file:/C:/Users/zekee/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.jar
    file:/C:/Users/zekee/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.pom
    
file:/C:/Users/zekee/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-

Comment: messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.jar
    https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-

Comment: messaging/16.0.3/firebase-messaging-16.0.3.jar
Required by:
    project :app

Comment: hey bro, i'm back. just did 3 exams. and today im still getting the no gcm and another error popped up. which is " error: method sendNotification in class FirebaseMessagingService cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String
found: Notification
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length "

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on your gradle

//Google Play Services

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

Comment: tried using it then this error showed up

" error: no suitable method found for d(String)
method Log.d(String,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Log.d(String,String,Throwable) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length) "

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

And this one:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

to

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```